# python multiprocessing Pool with map_async

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I trying to use the multiprocessing package in python with a Pool.

I have the function f which is called by the map_async function:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(host, x):
    print host
    print x

hosts = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']
pool = Pool(processes=5)
pool.map_async(f,hosts,"test")
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This code has the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pool-test.py", line 9, in <module>
    pool.map_async(f,hosts,"test")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 290, in map_async
    result = MapResult(self._cache, chunksize, len(iterable), callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 557, in __init__
    self._number_left = length//chunksize + bool(length % chunksize)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'int' and 'str'
```

I don't know how to pass more than 1 argument to the f function. Are there any way?

Comment: You just can use `pool.map` and drop the `"test"` dummy variable altogether.

Answer (score 13):

`"test"` is interpreted as `map_async`'s `chunksize` keyword argument (see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async)).

Your code should probably be (here copy-pasted from my IPython session) :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(arg):
    host, x = arg
    print host
    print x

hosts = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']
args = ((host, "test") for host in hosts)
pool = Pool(processes=5)
pool.map_async(f, args)
pool.close()
pool.join()
## -- End pasted text --

1.1.1.1
test
2.2.2.2
test
```

*Note: In Python 3 you can use `starmap`, which will unpack the arguments from the tuples. You'll be able to avoid doing `host, x = arg` explicitely.*

Comment: I tested it but the result is not good; it print both hosts but only the "t" and the "e" of the "test" word.

Comment: Weird. It definitely does not do that on my computer. See update for my results -- I copy-pasted and checked them again.

Comment: With x=["test","test"] it works but it has no sense because imagine that the hosts list is about 10000 and I only want one x for compare the results. It not viable to have an x list with 10000 entries with the same result. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: That was just a quick'n'dirty way of doing it in your simple example. Maybe see the updated version?

Comment: The result is the same. The generator produces the same number of "test" as number of hosts. It's the poor performance.

Comment: It doesn't keep them in memory and creates them on the fly, just like a regular `for` loop would do. You won't have any noticeable penalty, IMO. What are you trying to achieve with that list?

Comment: I want to pass to the f function to check if the hosts are alive using multiprocessing, but I need more than 1 argument.

Comment: Maybe you can just use a common function if the argument is common to each host, can't you?

Comment: Finally I used a global option. Really is a static variable.

Answer (score 6):

Pool returns a context manager in Python 3 and so a with statement can be used. This avoids problems with exceptions and means no necessity to close and join. In this case the function is always receiving a constant for the x variable and so this can be handled with a partial evaluation. map_async is lazy and so we need to get the result for the actions to happen, might as well just use map. Thus:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def f(host, x):
    print(host)
    print(x)

hosts = ('1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2')
with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
    pool.map(partial(f, x='test'), hosts)
```

results in:

```
1.1.1.1
test
2.2.2.2
test
```

Answer (score 1):

as I recall, the Pool().map() and .map_async() specifically accept only a single argument. this limitation can be worked around by passing a list, but of course then you need a customized function designed to take a list(like) object as an argument.

one approach is to write the custom code once -- aka, a general "function + args" wrapper. i worked up something like this (note: this is only partially tested):

```
def tmp_test():
    # a short test script:
    #
    A=[[1,2], [2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
    P=mpp.Pool(mpp.cpu_count())
    X=P.map_async(map_helper, [[operator.eq]+a for a in A])
    #
    return X.get()


def null_funct(args=[], kwargs={}):
    # a place-holder 
    pass
#
def map_helper(args_in = [null_funct, [], {}]):
    # helper function for pool.map_async(). pass data as a list(-like object):
    # [function, [args], {kwargs}] (though we'll allow for some mistakes).
    #
    funct = args_in[0]
    #
    # allow for different formatting options:
    if not (isinstance(args_in[1], list) or isinstance(args_in[1], tuple) or isinstance(args_in[1], dict)):
        # probably passed a list of parameters. just use them:
        args = args_in[1:]
        #
        return funct(*args)
    #
    # if the args are "properly" formatted:
    args=[]
    kwargs = {}
    for arg in args_in[1:]:
        # assign list types to args, dict types to kwargs...
        if isinstance(arg, list) or isinstance(arg, tuple): args += arg
        if isinstance(arg, dict): kwargs.update(arg)
    return funct(*args, **kwargs)
```